# dotnet core setting Cache-Control has no effect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I have configured the dotnet core middleware to output Cache-Control headers. I am looking to cache all static content, but most particularly several .png files. The **cache header** is **not being output?** I am using dotnet core 1.1.1.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = _ =>
            {
                var headers = _.Context.Request.GetTypedHeaders();
                headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                {
                    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(12)
                };
            }
        });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseIdentity();

    // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "default",
            "{controller=Site}/{action=Site}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

The code is being ignored, as evidenced by the below screenshot.

[image]

I have also tried explicitly adding the header like this, but I get errors indicating the header is already present.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = _ =>
    {
        _.Context.Request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "public,max-age=60");
    }
});
```

Somehow it's getting eaten up. If I set a breakpoint, the code is being called.

Comment: Did you force reload? It seems to say "disk cache" so it probably didn't even ask the server in this case if the info is logical

Comment: Yes I have, I replaced the screenshot with a new one showing this. I have also checked it with fiddler, somehow it's not being set. I have tested the live site with `www.webpagetest.org` which also indicates the headers are not being set.

Comment: you need  add to response header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you trying manipulate request header.

```
            var headers = _.Context.Request.GetTypedHeaders();
            headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
            {
                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(12)
            };
```

The browser needs a response header, not a request header. Add cache-control to the response header. It does not matter whether directly or via CacheHeader property.

```
_.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", string.Format("public,max-age={0}", TimeSpan.FromHours(12).TotalSeconds));
```

Comment: did not worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549204/asp-net-core-2-0-website-cache-control-not-working-as-expected